# What does 我们已经帮您踩过了 mean in this peculiarly translated escalator sticker?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

I have [this funny image](https://i.postimg.cc/htns2r1P/426973464.jpg) which I believe says:

> 这块位置
>   我们已经帮您踩过了！

I took this photo in Tianjin, nearby an escalator.  [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E8%BF%99%E5%9D%97%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE%0A%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC%E5%B7%B2%E7%BB%8F%E5%B8%AE%E6%82%A8%E8%B8%A9%E8%BF%87%E4%BA%86) says it means:

> This location.  We've helped you step over!

However, the second sentence is unclear to me.

**Question**: What does 我们已经帮您踩过了 mean in this peculiarly translated escalator sticker?

I don't understand what 已经 and 踩过 implies here.  I know [已经](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B7%B2%E7%BB%8F) = "already" and [踩](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B8%A9) = "stamp" and [过](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%87) = "pass", but this doesn't help much.

Comment: This is more of a cultural question: the connection betweem "safety-tested" and "being stamped/trodden on" is not as present in the West.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[过](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%87) doesn't mean "pass" here, from the dictionary link you posted:

> （用在动词后， 表示完毕）
>
> (used after verbs to denote completed state

So 踩过 means "has been stamped".

The background information is that there were several accidents of escalator's step; as the translation in the image said, the whole sentence means "we've already stepped on this area for you", indicating that "the safty has been confirmed, you can use the escalator with an easy mind".

Answer (score 13):

Please allow me to give you some background about this sticker.
On July 26th, 2015, one piece of plate, where the sticker is sitting, on an escalator turned over leaving a young women dead in Hubei China. This accident caused public in China worried about the safety of escalators, stepping onto a plate of an escalator may not safe.

Shortly after that, these stickers came out, stating that "We had already stepped onto this area", which indicate to the public, the escalator is safe.

Similar pictures can be found here: http://www.xdwy2001.com/a/kantianxia/2015/1229/5062.html

Comment: Yes, this is it. The sticker is intentionally being funny to assure passerbys.

Answer (score 4):

> [過](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/930/)
>
> [7] particle marking experiential aspect

Adding 過 after a verb marks that verb as a "perfect tense verb" (past, present or future)

Example:

踩 = step on

踩過 = had/ have stepped on

去 = go

去過 = had/ have gone

> 我们已经帮您踩过了！
>
> We've stepped on (this area) for you
>
> *Meaning we've tested it and it is sturdy and safe*

*"area" refers to an area on the escalator*